# Analog circuit to generate a pair of non-intersecting PWM signals

Tags: operational-amplifier, led, analog, pwm

I want to generate two PWM signals, each used to drive LEDs. The sum of both duty cycles will never exceed 100%, so I want the signals to be non-overlapping in order to limit peak currents.

The two channels are controlled by respective voltages IN1 and IN2, whose limits are set by reference voltages REF_TOP and REF_BOT such that `VCC > REF_TOP > REF_BOT > VSS`.

I want it so that when `IN1 ≥ REF_TOP`, PWM1 is at 100% duty cycle; when `IN1 ≤ REF_BOT`, PWM1 is at 0% duty cycle, and varies linearly in between. The same is true respctively for IN2 and PWM2.

So far, I have come up with this atrocity:
[image: schematic]
My idea goes like this:

- when the output of U3 is at minimum (close to VSS), the output of U5 gradually rises. When it reaches REF_TOP,  U1, acting as a comparator, brings its output close to VCC, which in turn, through D1, gets U3 to bring its output at maximum.
- when the output of U3 is at maximum, the output of U5 gradually goes down. When it reaches REF_BOT, U2 brings its output close to VCC, which in turn, through D2, gets U3 to bring its output at minimum.
- thus, at the output of U5, we get a triangular signal going up and down between REF_TOP and REF_BOT
- furthermore, U4 and U6 act in the same way as U3 and U5, but with reversed inputs - thus, at the output of U6, we also get a triangular wave locked between REF_TOP and REF_BOT, but with its phase exactly complementary to the other one
- now, comparators U7 and U8 give us PWM signals with complementary phase and the correct duty cycles, which are fed into MOSFET drivers U9 and U10.

Although this works in simulation, it has some drawbacks:

- the shape second triangle wave depends on C1 and C2 being completely identical - in practice, U6 will rise/fall a bit slower/faster than U5, which will make its triangle wave cut off / malformed, which will incur some inaccuracy in the PWM2 duty cycle
- it has many components (that's a lot of opamps!)

So, my questions are these:

- my [Y](https://xyproblem.info/) problem: **What is a less stupid way to generate complementary triangle waves locked between two reference voltages?**
- my [X](https://xyproblem.info/) problem: **Is there a better way to approach this entire problem**?

**Note**:
I am doing this with analog circuitry and not with a microcontroller because I need a relatively high frequency (about 20kHz) and granularity (about 14 bits). This would require a timer clocked at 300+ MHz.

Comment: It would be much simpler and much cheaper to use a microcontroller for this application

Comment: X - use a microcontroller or FPGA. Y - generate one waveform and then invert it.

Comment: hey dexterlb, I'm considering what to recommend re both X and Y, what's the purpose of these LEDs, why do you need a PWM frequency >= 20 kHz? maybe this is the case where a DAC + adjustable constant current DC/DC converter would work better?

Comment: @Neil_UK how would I go about inverting the waveform? Note that it is not centered around the midpoint, but rather around the `(REF_TOP - REF_BOT) / 2 + REF_BOT` point

Comment: @Damien what microcontroller would you recommend that would fit the constraints?

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Suppose I'm lighting a scene which shall be video-captured with a camera.

For high-power fixtures, say 50W, I have used the exact approach you proposed: generating a reference voltage with a PWM + lowpass filter and then using it to control a constant-current buck converter, and it works great.

I was wondering if for lower-power lights (like consumer LED strips) I could use something like a high-frequency PWM, since adjusting current seems both overkill and out-of-spec for led strips.

The frequency constraint is because anything less causes video artifacts.

Comment: @dexterlb ah! Interesting field, I was always curious how film production solved that issue (and I assumed they had a central clock source to which they synchronized frame capture, audio recording  anyways, and then had expensive specialty synchronized lighting controllers).

Comment: @dexterlb re: microcontroller candidates: STM32H7? Generally, things that are meant to drive high-power motors and DC/DC converters would be fast enough, I guess.

Comment: @dexterlb Invert it about its midpoint. Use a standard gain of -1 amplifier, with equal value resistors to the opamp inverting input, one from the signal input, one from the output, and take the amplifier's non-inverting input to the midpoint voltage you want to invert about.

Comment: @Neil_UK thanks - inverting the waveform in this matter works and eliminates the first drawback

Comment: If you'd use analog dimming instead, you had no problems. I don't think a 14 bit resolution is realistic as this will still leaves strips in the recorded video. On the other hand, some cameras (like my samsung mobile phone camera) do not get strips at all even if recording 500Hz PWM light. I don't know why, but some cameras might eliminate the problem due to their shutter or processing. Anyway, the only save solution I see is to use a proper led driver

Comment: @dexterlb basically any controller can do the job, 20khz is nothing for a (recent) micro. Check Microchip 8bits, 16, 32bits. You can probably find a micro for 1-2$ that does the job and replace 28 components. If you want to push it you can take one with hardware PWM but at 20khz it's not even necessary.

Comment: @Damien this appears to be utterly untrue: can you give me one example of a sub-$10 microcontroller that would do?

Comment: @SimSon you're probably right that 20kHz might not be enough - to be absolutely sure, you'd have to make the waveform faster than the row scan frequency of the camera - and for 1080p30fps that's 56.7kHz.

I wanted to try, though

Comment: @dexterlb Hi. Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: @Behrooz not really, I just designed for a bigger power supply filter so that peak currents with overlapping PWM signals aren't so much of an issue